# Issue With Replacing RegExp Terms In String

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var testString = "This string has a bad word in it to test";

function findBadWords(string) {
  var badWord = /\bbad\b | \bword\b | \btest\b/gi
  var isBadWord = string.match(badWord);
  if (isBadWord) {
    newString = string.replace(badWord," *** ");
  }
  document.write(newString);
}
findBadWords(testString);
```

So I'm practicing with RegExp's currently and I have run into a problem I don't understand. In the code above, I have set a RegExp to find "bad words" in a string. From what I can tell, I have set it to find the word "bad", "word", and "test" as long as there is a word boundary before and after the word. The issue I'm having is that "word" isn't being replaced. If I put a non-badWord before "word" it gets replaced, but not otherwise. I have tried taking off some of the word boundaries or adding some non-word boundaries with no luck. Would anyone mind explaining why this code is working the way that it is and how I could fix it?

Thanks!

Also, I know using document.write is a poor choice but it's only for testing I swear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is the `\b` alongside the " " empty space character.  If you remove the spaces from your regex it works well.

```
var testString = "This string has a bad word in it to test";

function findBadWords(string) {
    var badWord = /\bbad\b|\bword\b|\btest\b/gi
    var isBadWord = string.match(badWord);
    if (isBadWord) {
        newString = string.replace(badWord," *** ");
    }
    document.write(newString);
}
findBadWords(testString);
```

Comment: Ah of course! Thank you for the quick response!!